# Хочу отображать блокнот на Lock Screen Windows 10

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-10

Хочу, чтобы на Lock Screen (экране блокировки) отображался блокнотик. Код обваливается на этой строчке:

```
if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(newToken, false, ref tokPrivs, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
```

> Ошибка "Параметр задан неверно. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))"

Чистка `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files` не помогает и вообще, там пусто.
Что делать, подскажите, пожалуйста?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


#region DllImport - Kernel32
#endregion
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern int GetProcessId(IntPtr handle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool CreateProcess(
    string lpApplicationName,
    string lpCommandLine,
    bool bInheritHandles,
    uint dwCreationFlags,
    IntPtr lpEnvironment,
    string lpCurrentDirectory,
    [In] ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
    out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);



    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WTSQueryUserToken(UInt32 sessionId, out IntPtr Token);


    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public static extern int WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();


    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private extern static bool DuplicateTokenEx(
        IntPtr hExistingToken,
        uint dwDesiredAccess,
       ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpTokenAttributes,
        SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL ImpersonationLevel,
        TOKEN_TYPE TokenType,
        out IntPtr phNewToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(

        IntPtr hToken,
        string lpApplicationName,
        string lpCommandLine,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
        bool bInheritHandles,
        uint dwCreationFlags,

        IntPtr lpEnvironment,
        string lpCurrentDirectory,
        ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,

        out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr TokenHandle,
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]bool DisableAllPrivileges,
   ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES NewState,
   uint Zero,
   IntPtr Null1,
   IntPtr Null2);



    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr ProcessHandle,
        UInt32 DesiredAccess, out IntPtr TokenHandle);
    public const UInt32 STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000;
    public const UInt32 STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = 0x00020000;
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x0001;
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0x0004;
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008;
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = 0x0010;
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x0020;
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = 0x0040;
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x0080;
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID = 0x0100;
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_READ = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ | TOKEN_QUERY);
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY |
        TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE |
        TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS | TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT |
        TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID);
    const string SE_DEBUG_NAME = "SeDebugPrivilege";
    const Int32 SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x0002;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public int nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public int bInheritHandle;
    }
    enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
    {
        SecurityAnonymous,
        SecurityIdentification,
        SecurityImpersonation,
        SecurityDelegation
    }

    public enum TOKEN_TYPE
    {
        TokenPrimary = 1,
        TokenImpersonation
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
    {
        public UInt32 PrivilegeCount;
        public LUID Luid;
        public UInt32 Attributes;
        public LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[] Privileges;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct LUID
    {
        public uint LowPart;
        public int HighPart;
    }
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string lpSystemName, string lpName,
        out LUID lpLuid);
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public Int32 cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public Int32 dwX;
        public Int32 dwY;
        public Int32 dwXSize;
        public Int32 dwYSize;
        public Int32 dwXCountChars;
        public Int32 dwYCountChars;
        public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
        public Int32 dwFlags;
        public Int16 wShowWindow;
        public Int16 cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public int dwProcessId;
        public int dwThreadId;
    }
    [Flags]
    enum CreateProcessFlags : uint
    {
        DEBUG_PROCESS = 0x00000001,
        DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS = 0x00000002,
        CREATE_SUSPENDED = 0x00000004,
        DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008,
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010,
        NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00000020,
        IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00000040,
        HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00000080,
        REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00000100,
        CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200,
        CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400,
        CREATE_SEPARATE_WOW_VDM = 0x00000800,
        CREATE_SHARED_WOW_VDM = 0x00001000,
        CREATE_FORCEDOS = 0x00002000,
        BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00004000,
        ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00008000,
        INHERIT_PARENT_AFFINITY = 0x00010000,
        INHERIT_CALLER_PRIORITY = 0x00020000,
        CREATE_PROTECTED_PROCESS = 0x00040000,
        EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT = 0x00080000,
        PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN = 0x00100000,
        PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_END = 0x00200000,
        CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB = 0x01000000,
        CREATE_PRESERVE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL = 0x02000000,
        CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE = 0x04000000,
        CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000,
        PROFILE_USER = 0x10000000,
        PROFILE_KERNEL = 0x20000000,
        PROFILE_SERVER = 0x40000000,
        CREATE_IGNORE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT = 0x80000000,
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public LUID Luid;
        public UInt32 Attributes;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RunProcess p = new RunProcess();
        p.StartProcess(@"c:\windows\notepad.exe");

    }
    public class RunProcess
    {

        public static void log(String error)
        {
            String a = error;
        }
        public void StartProcess(string pathOrName)
        {

            Process winLogon = null;
            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (p.ProcessName.Contains("winlogon"))
                {
                    winLogon = p;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // grab the winlogon's token
            IntPtr userToken = IntPtr.Zero;
            if (!OpenProcessToken(winLogon.Handle, TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_DUPLICATE, out userToken))
                  log("ERROR: OpenProcessToken returned false - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());


            // create a new token
            IntPtr newToken = IntPtr.Zero;
            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES tokenAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            tokenAttributes.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(tokenAttributes);
            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            threadAttributes.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(threadAttributes);
            // duplicate the winlogon token to the new token
            if (!DuplicateTokenEx(userToken, 0x10000000, ref tokenAttributes, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation,
                TOKEN_TYPE.TokenImpersonation, out newToken))
            {
                log("ERROR: DuplicateTokenEx returned false - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }
            TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tokPrivs = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES();
            tokPrivs.PrivilegeCount = 1;
            LUID seDebugNameValue = new LUID();
            if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(null, SE_DEBUG_NAME, out seDebugNameValue))
                log("ERROR: LookupPrivilegeValue returned false - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            tokPrivs.Privileges = new LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[1];
            tokPrivs.Privileges[0].Luid = seDebugNameValue;
            tokPrivs.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
            // escalate the new token's privileges
            if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(newToken, false, ref tokPrivs, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
                log("ERROR: AdjustTokenPrivileges returned false - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
            STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
            si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
            si.lpDesktop = @"Winsta0\Winlogon";

            // start the process using the new token
            if (!CreateProcessAsUser(newToken, "notepad.exe", null, ref tokenAttributes, ref threadAttributes,
     true, (uint)CreateProcessFlags.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | (uint)CreateProcessFlags.INHERIT_CALLER_PRIORITY, IntPtr.Zero,
     @"C:\Windows\", ref si, out pi))
                log("ERROR: CreateProcessAsUser returned false - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            Process _p = Process.GetProcessById(pi.dwProcessId);
            if (_p != null)
                log("Process " + _p.Id + " Name " + _p.ProcessName);
            else
                log("Process not found");
        }

    }

   }
}
```

Comment: DuplicateTokenEx() успешно проходит? newToken при вызове AdjustTokenPrivileges() не нулевой ли?